# Rate of polymerization for copolymers with two monomers

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics, polymers, chemical-engineering

I've found in textbooks that for a chain growth homopolymerization the rate of polymerization $r_\mathrm{p}$ is

$$r_\mathrm{p} = k_\mathrm{p}\sqrt{\frac{f_\mathrm{kd}}{k_\mathrm{t}}}c_\ce{A}^ac_\ce{B}^b,$$

where $k_\mathrm{p}$ is the rate constant of propagation; $k_\mathrm{t}$ is the rate constant of termination; $f_\mathrm{kd}$ is the constant for chain initiation.

What is the rate equation for chain growth copolymerization $r_\mathrm{p}$ such as styrene-butadiene rubber (SBR) synthesis? In many polymer textbooks it only shows the [Mayo–Lewis equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayo%E2%80%93Lewis_equation) which I understand is not the $r_\mathrm{p}$ equation required for volumes calculations for reactors.